# Percentage Scaling when using data in excel

Tags: percentages, data-analysis

I have data in percentage, and the smallest value is 18.96% and largest is 95.85.
What I'm trying to do is scale the data in a way that makes 18.96% to be 40% and 95.85% to be 100%.

Comment: Please, provide more information about the context of your question.

Comment: Yeah you need to provide more information, like what exactly do you mean by scaling the data?